# R/stringr: Regex to acquire specific symbol within a specific part of a string

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr

I have a few character strings such as the one below:

```
> TstStr <- c("Carnivora, Caniformia, Canidae (dog, coyote, wolf, fox), Canis, Canis lupus (Gray wolf), Canis lupus familiaris (Dog) (Canis familiaris)")
> TstStr
[1] "Carnivora, Caniformia, Canidae (dog, coyote, wolf, fox), Canis, Canis lupus (Gray wolf), Canis lupus familiaris (Dog) (Canis familiaris)"
```

> I want to replace **only** the commas and spaces inside the parentheses with the dollar sign if they occur together, ideally using `stringr:str_replace_all` (or something equivalent). So I would like the output to look like this:

```
> TstStr
[1] "Carnivora, Caniformia, Canidae (dog$coyote$wolf$fox), Canis, Canis lupus (Gray wolf), Canis lupus familiaris (Dog) (Canis familiaris)"
```

I have no clue what the regex for such a scenario should look like, as my knowledge of regex is rudimentary. I tried `str_match_all(Tstr, "(?<=\\()(?:[:alpha:]*)\\,\\s(?:[:alpha:]*)(?=\\))")` but this didn't work (obviously). Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @NelsonGon Commas must be replaced with dollar signs.

Comment: @NelsonGon Sorry for the bad phrasing, I'll fix it. Edit: I see it's been fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
library(stringr)
TstStr <- c("Carnivora, Caniformia, Canidae (dog, coyote, wolf, fox), Canis, Canis lupus (Gray wolf), Canis lupus familiaris (Dog) (Canis familiaris)")
str_replace_all(TstStr, "\\([^()]*\\)", function(x) { gsub("\\s*,\\s*", "$", x) })
[1] "Carnivora, Caniformia, Canidae (dog$coyote$wolf$fox), Canis, Canis lupus (Gray wolf), Canis lupus familiaris (Dog) (Canis familiaris)"
```

The `\\([^()]*\\)` pattern will match `(...)` substrings with no parentheses inside and a `gsub` with the `"\\s*,\\s*"` pattern will replace commas enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars with `$` chars inside the matches.

**Regex detals**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The strings matched with this pattern are passed to the anonymous function that is a third argument to `str_replace_all` and then, `gsub` replaces all cases of

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `,` - comma
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces

with `$` symbols in the whole match, and the modified matches are returned back and used as replacements for the regex matches found with `str_extract_all`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain how this works? I'm interested in learning how to use regex as much as (if not more than) having a solution to this specific problem.

Comment: `str_replace_all(Tstr, "\\([A-Za-z\\s\\,]*\\)", function(x){str_replace_all(x, "\\,\\s", "$")})` also appears to work. This was the original solution I was trying to implement, but I didn't know how to go about it until I saw your use of `gsub`. Many thanks!

Comment: You can also use the interactive tutorial at [regexone.com](https://regexone.com/)